# Google calendar api CalendarList List return empty element

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

**EDIT:** The original poster asked this for `C#`, but the same problem occurs regardless of the library used, and its solution is **language independent**.

Using C# lib,

```
        string service_account = "myaccount@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"pathtomy-privatekey.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
           new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(service_account)
           {
               Scopes = new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar }
           }.FromCertificate(certificate));


        // Create the service.
        var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "My project name",

        });

        var calendarList = service.CalendarList.List().Execute();
        IList<CalendarListEntry> items = calendarList.Items;
```

items is empty. On https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list, when I try the api, I get the good result.

I really don't understand why I don't have any result : seems like if the service_account do not have the same calendar as my gmail account linked to.

Any suggestion ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The solution is to share the existing calendar with the service account

`<paste-your-account-here>@developer.gserviceaccount.com`

(You can find the account in question under the `credentials` tab in Google Developers Console, it's called 'EMAIL ADDRESS')

Comment: @aldanux - What are you talking about? This is **exactly** the solution to the problem.

Comment: @Rototo - Thank you a ton, I was stuck on this since an hour and didn't know what to try next! You saved my day... :)

Comment: After sharing the calendar with the service account, the calendar list still appeared empty for me. After I shared a SECOND calendar with the service account, both appeared. I almost pulled my hair out before stumbling onto this solution, so if you're still stuck, maybe it will help.

Comment: Perhaps obvious, but I missed it the first time: it's not enough to paste the address in to the Calendar settings page and press return, you also need to click 'Save' - it's not until that point it becomes live.

Comment: …also: if you're using a Google Apps domain, it may have the highest level of calendar sharing restricted to "Only free/busy information" – so you'll be able to see events but the titles etc. will be blank.  Plus it doesn't warn you this has happened - you'll just eventually notice the "Permission Settings" in Calendar are wrong.  You can change this in Apps > Google Apps > Settings for Calendar; I found I needed to log out of the account in question then log back in.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice, it works!
Why the hell it's mentioned nowhere in the Calendar's API doc?!!!

Comment: I have the exact same issue myself as @alex83. Only after adding a second calendar shared to the service account did anything appear in the list. I only get one calendar against the account email though, not both. And yes, have ensured to click 'save' and verified the service account is shared on both by using the calendar event API to request by calendar ID manually via the service account.

Comment: Update - went back into the missing calendar, deleted the service account email, saved, added the email again, saved. Now it comes up.