# Google Calendar API with Java - Service Account

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

Referenced [Google Calendar API with PHP – Service Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818380/google-calendar-api-with-php-service-account) and tried the following steps:

- Created a project in Google API console and enabled Google Calendar API on this project
- Created a service account under the project, downloaded the JWT format key
- Tried to share my personal calendar with the service account email, not sure whether it's UI bug or not allowed, there's no error, after refreshing the page, the service account email is gone. I had to use my company's Google account calendar and the service account can be added.
- Wrote Java code to use the JWT key from step 2, to get the Calendar list.

---

```
HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
// Build service account credential.

GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential          .fromStream(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("makoto-c14c149ef994.json")).createScoped(Collections.singleton(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR));

Calendar calendar = new Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName("makoto").build();

return calendar.calendarList().list();
```

**The problems/questions are:**

1. nothing listed from

> calendar.calendarList().list()

which returned [], no error as well. did I miss anything?

2. why can't I share my personal calendar with the service account. Is this only available to enterprise google account?

Answer (score 2):

For #1, try to do the suggestion here in the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24063327).

Regardless of language used, try to share the existing calendar with the service account.

```
<paste-your-account-here>@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```

To have an insight of #2, try to follow the accepted answer in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34944402).

> Go to the Google calendar website add the service account email
>   address as a user of your calendar. Then the service account will be
>   able to access it. If you want you can programmatically insert it into
>   calendar.list if you really need it to be there.

Answer (score -1):

Please try

```
return calendar.calendarList().list().execute();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.